# Laravel Join Query returning empty column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a **member** table with some entries. Each member can create a user account in laravel's **users** table.

They each have a field called **"person_id"** and that's how the connection is made.

I have a search that returns a list with all of them. I have a checkbox "Search only registered" that means it returns only members that have users account, otherwise if the check doesn't check, return a mix with all of them.

The thing is, no matter if the checkbox is checked or not, the person_id must be pulled for each one.

```
if($reg == 'on') {
        $Members = $Members->rightJoin('users', 'users.person_id', '=', 'members.person_id');
    }
    else {
        $Members = $Members->leftJoin('users', 'users.person_id', '=', 'members.person_id');
    }
```

I tried with leftJoin but person_id comes empty

Comment: post your table structure user and member. also print your query too.

Answer (score 0):

at first look if you are using Eloquent i can tell you are missing the "->get();" at the end of each query.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use relation in member model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'person_id', 'person_id' );
}

public function getMemberWithUser()
{
    return $this->select('*')->with('user')->get()->toArray();
}
```

and use `(new Member)->getMemberWithUser();` in controller. That will return you member detail with user.

Answer (score 0):

Neverming guys I found it out.

Most members don't have yet a user account, only 2. And the select wasn't specifying which table to take the person_id from. And with most members missing an user account, it was trying to get it from users.

I did this:

```
 $Participants = Member::select(
        'members.first_name',
        'members.last_name',
        'members.person_id',
        'members.email'
    );
```